# Python scripts not working after connecting more than 2 controllers

Tags: python, game-engine

I'm making a bomberman like game and like the titles says, after I connect more than 2 usb controllers to the game, it's like the python script no longer runs, I have written a script that helps me place bombs, and it works fine with only 2 players connected.

I find this really hard to debug, anyone have a suggestion on what I can try to do?

Has anyone tried making a 4 player local game in blender?

Comment: We are going to need more information. If it's a script error, what does it say in the console?

Comment: I don't know what to say... it's not a script error :) and there comes no error in the console.

Comment: You could post the scripts you are using plus a description how you run it.

Comment: I blew my deadline yesterday, I did not expect the game to only work partially when I connect more controllers...  

so I'm going to make a in depth description of the project I'm making, probably make a website for it, and split the game op in smaller packages, so the different problem is easy to differentiate from each other, and so i link to a .blend to other ppl without giving them a big project.